# Creating a dataset from attributes in QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing, select-by-attribute, feature-dataset

I need to select just a field from a dataset to compose a model in QGIS 3.4 modeler.
How could I extract this field from the main dataset while creating another one?.

I've tried with `Drop field(s)` but the dataset is to large to enumerate everyfield and make the task efficient.

I also tried `Extract by attribute` but it returns a blank attribute table with every field from the main dataset but no features.

The output should be similar to a pandas data selection like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
df_select = pd.DataFrame(df['field_name'])
```

Comment: I solved it myself. You should make a filter inthe algorithm menu